Expo mod plugins added to app.json to modify java memory settings not working
"mods": {`
      "android": {
        "gradleProperties": [
          {
            "type": "comment",
            "value": "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m"
          },
          {
            "type": "property",
            "key": "org.gradle.jvmargs",
            "value": "-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
          }
        ]
      }
    },

I need to tweak java memory for my project to build and i tried to change using this rather than directly modifying native folders, but somehow this code is not working.

whats not wroking here. do you mind adding error logs or anything by which you determine thats its not working.
